# why the session is lost after redirect in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.5

I implementing a payment gateway with flywire in laravel. 
i have a method that update a data to a crm without problem, i need this data  when is called to another method that make a redirect to a external url (is a wizard) the trouble is that after maked the redirection the value of sessions are lost. 
How can I holding those values ​​after redirecting to an external url?

```
    use Session;
    public function update(Request $request)
        {
            //code..
            Session::put('value1',$request->val1);
            Session::put('value2',$request->val2);
            $url = 'https://www.urldemo.payment.com/payment/';
            $data=[
            'value1'= $request->val1,
            'value2' = $request->val2,
            ];
            $params = json_encode($data);
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
            try{
               $response = curl_exec($curl);    
               $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
               $err = curl_error($curl);
               curl_close($curl);        
               return response()->json(['success'=>'the update was completed success','url'=> $url],200);

            }catch(Exception $e){
             return response()->json(['errors'=> $e->getMessage()],422);
            }
}
/*This function retrieve the response data from the payment update*/
public function returnData(Request $request){
    $obj = json_decode($request->getContent());
    if(Session::exists('value1')){
     $p1 = $obj->id;
    }elseif(Session::exists('value2')){
     $p2 = $obj->id;
    }else{
      $p1 = '';
      $p2 = '';
    }
    $data2 = [
    'value1' => $p1,
    'value2' => $p2,
    ];
    $values = json_encode($data2);
    dd($values); 
    /*Here print the $p1 and $p2 empty thats after redirect to a external url the point is that here the session is lost*/
}
```

My question at this moment is how can i hold the sessions after redirect in Laravel 5.5 ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any redirect in this code. Can you clarify?

Comment: i make a redirect to this url 'https://www.urldemo.payment.com/payment' in update method look the response. after that the function returnData retrieve the data from https://www.urldemo.payment.com/payment to the function but for this exist another parameters that this url retrieve thats a reason why i put $obj json_decode($request->getContent()); i get the response in json format from the url.

Comment: You're not redirecting, though. You're making a curl request, and you're outputting the URL in your JSON response. Neither one of those things issues a redirect.

Comment: if(response.status==200){
 this.getProfile();
 console.log(response.data.url);
 res = response.data.success;
 toastr.success(res);
             setTimeout(function () {window.location= response.data.url},3500);
}
 }).catch(error =>{
//console.log(error.response);
if(error.response.status==422){
this.errors=  error.response.data.errors;
$.each(error.response.data.errors, function (i,v){
toastr.error(v);
  });
}

Comment: If you're expecting value1/value2 to be included when you send the user there client-side, it's not going to work. The curl call will be completely separate - it happens (essentially) in a totally separate browser and session from the user's browser.

Comment: how can i make a solution for that?.. any suggestions lines above i has a code in js that make the redirection to another website, but how can i hold the session variable then?.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the payment gateway, and that gateway should generally provide a sample implementation or documentation on how to do all this. Session variables only exist on *your* site - you can't pass data to other sites in a session.

Comment: thats becouse im using curl, curl doesn't manage session, thats a reason why the session lost, exist a form to hold a session and send it with CURL?.

Comment: You can't use a session to send data to the payment gateway, regardless of method.